# How to profile JavaEE-REST endpoint with JProfiler 10

Tags: jackson, java-ee-6, jprofiler

I use JProfiler 10 to profile a call to a JavaEE REST endpoint, that serializes into JSON. My guess is that a lot of time is spent with serialization.

When I start recordings for the call tree then the serialization overhead is not included in the metrics so I observe pure business logic there (1 second).

When I use the JEE Servlet probe I see the correct total time (4 seconds) but no further details, no other method calls except the mere call to the resource path.

I have tried to disable all filters but that did not change the situation.

How can I profile everything what is going on with that servlet call?

Any help appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: Have you tried to use sampling (not instrumentation) and disable all filters?

Comment: I use sampling and have disabled all filters. Instrumentation with all filters disabled won't let the app server start.

Comment: Can you add a screen shot of what you are seeing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the answer and solution: The call tree view shows "Thread status: Runnable" by default. I have to change this to "Thread status: All states" to see the "correct" times - in my context there was not so obviously lots of "Net IO" which was hidden before.